# Sending Data from html to Flask

Tags: python, html, post, flask

So I'm trying to send data from an html form to my python flask framework. 
Here's the example of the html code I'm using

```
<form method=post action=/test>
<input name=Name value=Austin type=hidden><input type=submit value="Add Notification">
```

and here's the python flask I'm working with

```
 @app.route('/test', methods=('GET', 'POST')
def test_page():
    v = request.values.get('Name')
    return v
```

I've tried many different request methods and can't seem to get it to work and I get a 405 error. I'm not very familiar with the flask web development or using post requests. If anyone could point me in the correct direction then that'd be great!

Comment: You could use jQuery and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) performing a post request combined with the button onclick-event.

Comment: @albert Is there no way to keep it to just python and html? it seems like this should work

Answer (score 3):

You're `POST`ing to your endpoint, but `app.route` by [default](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.route) only enables `GET`. Change `app.route('/test')` to `app.route('/test', methods=('GET', 'POST'))`, and you'll be able to access your endpoint.

That `405` response you're getting is [Method Not Allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#405).

(Unrelated issue, `request.values.get['Name']` should be `request.values.get('Name')`.)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm not longer getting the error. However now the webpage displays "None" instead of the Name. Any way you could guide me to the source of this issue?

Comment: @BigBoy I'm unable to reproduce `None` here. Using the code you provided (after fixing some syntax errors), I get `Austin`.

Comment: @jonfato for some reason, once I restarted my computer it displays the name Austin, but if I change the name field it stays as Austin. It never changes

Comment: @BigBoy sounds like a caching issue. Have you tried doing refreshing / clearing your browser cache?